# Symfony2 bundles with same routing

Tags: symfony, routes, bundle

I have two bundles in sf2, each have a same rout. example: /blog

Bundle A

```
user_blog:
    pattern:  /blog
    defaults: { _controller: UserBlogBundle:Default:blog }
```

Bundle B

```
team_blog:
    pattern:  /blog
    defaults: { _controller: TeamBlogBundle:Default:blog }
```

and with a session parameter i'll know which is the bundle will run the request

sorry,

I want to run the correct bundle according to the session parameter

example

```
{{
if($Parameter ='A')
 run user_blog
else
 run team_blog
}}
```

I make this:

```
//src/project/TestBundle
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

$collection = new RouteCollection();
$req = $this->getRequest();
if($req->server->get('SERVER_NAME') == 'www.domainA.com')
$collection->addCollection($loader->import("@BundleABundle/Resources/config/routing.php"));
else
$collection->addCollection($loader->import("@BundleBBundle/Resources/config/routing.php"));
return $collection;
```

this is the usual?

Comment: Did you try your code? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: not tryed yet, wanted to do the best, I'm looking for a more 'beautiful' way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's solved on 2.2 version parameter host

http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html

```
Bundle A

user_blog:
    pattern:  /blog
    host: a.example.com
    defaults: { _controller: UserBlogBundle:Default:blog }

Bundle B

team_blog:
    pattern:  /blog
    host: b.example.com
    defaults: { _controller: TeamBlogBundle:Default:blog }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, each route must be unique. You should build your application having that in mind. Otherwise, I think you might get some random behaviours when accessing those routes.